# Create plotting function with one input that uses two data frames in one plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create function which takes one argument and the output is one plot with two lines comparing price of S&P 500 index with CO2 emissions over the last years, starting 2000 for selected country.

```
from pandas_datareader import wb
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_comparison(selected_country)
```

I have two data frames. One has CO2 emission data for many countries and for each year starting 2000 as shown on image or as a code below: [df_co2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7SJn.png)

```
        country                         year    co2 emissions
0       Africa Eastern and Southern     2018    600351.133333
1       Africa Eastern and Southern     2017    601323.394691
2       Africa Eastern and Southern     2016    592299.593959
3       Africa Eastern and Southern     2015    586385.004029
4       Africa Eastern and Southern     2014    601860.163983
... ... ... ...
5049    Zimbabwe                        2004    9770.000000
5050    Zimbabwe                        2003    10180.000000
5051    Zimbabwe                        2002    12490.000000
5052    Zimbabwe                        2001    13900.000000
5053    Zimbabwe                        2000    13700.000000
```

And second data frame contains yearly closing prices of S&P 500 index as shown on image or as a code below: [df_spx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZKYA.png)

```
    year    Close
0   2000    1320.280029
1   2001    1148.079956
2   2002    879.820007
3   2003    1111.920044
4   2004    1211.920044
5   2005    1248.290039
6   2006    1418.300049
7   2007    1468.359985
8   2008    903.250000
9   2009    1115.099976
...
```

And this is the code I got so far, but it is not working (obviously) and I can't move forward. Getting this error:

> NameError: name 'country' is not defined

```
def plot_comparison(selected_country):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1,
                           nrows=1, 
                           figsize=(15,6), 
                           dpi=100)
        
    for selected_country in df_co2:
        country_df = df_co2[df_co2['country'] == selected_country].copy()
        ax.plot(country_df['year'], country_df['co2 emissions'], label=country)

    ax.set_xlabel('Year', fontsize=12)        
    ax.set_ylabel('CO2 value', fontsize=12) 

    fig.legend(fontsize=12)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: @Mr.T Hi, I think you misunderstood the desired output. My goal is to create a function that takes one argument (name of a country in data frame df_co2) and plot it together with S&P 500 index. So basically two lines, one for CO2 emission values in given country over the year and second one with closing prices of S&P 500 index over the same years. Is it clear now or should I improve my interpretation skills. New to programming.

Comment: Ah, okay. A comparison by country. So, why can't you add now `ax.plot(df_spx['year'], df_spx['close'], label="S&P 500 index")`?

Comment: @Mr.T I need to plot only two lines: one for S&P 500 and second one for CO2 emissions of a country user inputted into function, e.g. `plot_comparison('Zimbabwe')`.

Comment: @Mr.T I've got NameError: name 'country' is not defined. Not sure why it is not seeing it in data frame...

Comment: You defined the variable as `selected_country` in your function.

Comment: @Mr.T I though I have to specify column from data frame there. Where should I specify it? When I just change it to `selected_country` it gives me `KeyError: 'selected_country'`

Answer (score 0):

Not clear where the error message comes from. But as you will need to adapt a [twin axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-two-scales-py) approach because of the hugely different data ranges, here is a complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


#sample data generation
import numpy as np
n = 30
np.random.seed(123)
country_list = list("ABCDE")
df_co2 = pd.DataFrame({"country": np.repeat(country_list, n), 
                       "year": np.tile(range(2010, 2010+n), len(country_list)), 
                       "co2 emissions": np.random.randint(10000, 200000, n * len(country_list))})    
df_spx = pd.DataFrame({"year": np.arange(2010, 2010+n), 
                       "close": np.random.randint(1000, 2000, n)})


#here starts your modified function  
def plot_comparison(selected_country):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1,
                           nrows=1, 
                           figsize=(15,6), 
                           dpi=100)
    
    #filter for selected country 
    #and sort for year, just in case the year column is not sorted yet  
    df_plot = df_co2[df_co2["country"] == selected_country].sort_values('year')
    #plot into the axis object
    df_plot.plot(x='year', y='co2 emissions', color="blue", label=f"country is {selected_country}", ax=ax, legend=False)
    #set the axis limits to the minimum and maximum values 
    #so that the data for different countries are represented at the same scale
    ax.set_ylim(df_co2['co2 emissions'].min(), df_co2['co2 emissions'].max())
    ax.set_xlabel('Year', fontsize=12)        
    ax.set_ylabel('CO2 value', fontsize=12) 
    
    #create a twin axis because the values of the two series will differ substantially 
    ax1 = ax.twinx()
    #plot the second line onto the twin axis
    df_spx.sort_values('year').plot(x='year', y='close', color="red", label="S&P 500", ax=ax1, legend=False)  
    ax1.set_ylabel('Close', fontsize=12) 

    fig.legend(fontsize=12, loc="upper center", ncol=2)
    plt.show()


#call the function
for item in ["A", "C", "D"]:
    plot_comparison(item)
```

Sample output (1 of 3):
[image]